# How can I get a collection of collection

Tags: python, google-app-engine, collections, referenceproperty

I have these models:

```
class Country(db.Model):
    name    = db.StringProperty()
    code    = db.StringProperty()

class Course(db.Model):
    name          = db.StringProperty()
    description   = db.StringProperty()
    country       = db.ReferenceProperty(Country, collection_name='courses')

class Application():
    status    = db.StringProperty()
    course    = db.ReferenceProperty(Course, collection_name='applications')
```

One country has many courses, and one course has many applications.
So how can I get a query with all the applications from a country?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GAE datastore is not a relational model. You cannot do joins. You would need to iterate through each course to get its applications.

Comment: If its a query you perform a lot, then store the country  as redundant copy in the Application as an application can only refer to one course, and the course is explicity referencing a country.